# Get last n of each group

Tags: r, dplyr

let's say I have data like this:

```
df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
              value = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 1))
```

I want to reshape the data so that the last 4 values occuring are considered. That is:

```
A tibble: 2 × 5
     id  last last2 last3 last4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     2     1    NA
2     2     1     4     5     1
```

So far, I achieved to extract the last value with

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(last = dplyr::last(value))
```

Any ideas how to proceeed?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
 slice_tail(n = 4, by = id) %>%
 mutate(value = rev(value), .by = id) %>%
 mutate(rn = rowid(id)) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = value, names_prefix = 'last')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id last1 last2 last3 last4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     2     1    NA
2     2     1     4     5     1
```

---

Or with `unnest`

```
 df %>% 
  reframe(last = list(rev(tail(value, 4))), .by = id) %>% 
  unnest_wider(last, names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id last1 last2 last3 last4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     2     1    NA
2     2     1     4     5     1
```